# iPhone programming Quartz Slow

Tags: iphone, performance, drawing, quartz-graphics

I'm making a game which requires multiple images to be drawn on the screen. The code I'm using for this is:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
   for (i=1;i<=totalImages;i++) {
       if (imageExists[i]) {
           [image drawAtPoint:CGPointmake(imageX[i],imageY[i])];
       }
   }
}
```

This drawRect is called by a function:

```
-(void) gameLoop {
   [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

And the gameloop is called 60 timers per second by a timer:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimerInterval:0.01666 target:self selector:@selector(gameLoop) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

imageExists[], imageX[] and imageY[] are arrays I use in my gamecode to create/remove and move the images across the screen.

My problem is that when I have about 40 images moving around the framespeed is almost halved from when there was only 1 image. And my game will require 88 images max. (this only happens when I test it on my iPod Touch, in the Simulator everything works fine...)

My question is: why is the drawrect function that slow, or is it the drawAtPoint? And how can I fix this? Should I actually use this for drawing images, or should I learn OpenGL ES for making games?

Comment: I'm not going to suggest this as an answer because I don't know the effects, but what happens if you instead use CALayers as your sprites. Just call -setContents on the CALayers after setting their bounds passing a CGImage to initialize each of them. Then animate the sprites by calling -setPosition on the layers (or by using explicit animations). The reason I suggest this is because Core Animation runs on top of OpenGL without having to explicitly use OpenGL. I just wonder if it would give you better performance.

Comment: @Matt - You should make this an answer, because it's a perfectly valid solution to his performance problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to look into a game library like [cocos2d-iphone](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) which takes care of most of the OpenGL stuff for you behind the scenes.  It will get much higher performance for typical game functions than Quartz and CoreAnimation, and includes things like physics and sound libraries for integrated game interactivity.

The primary thing writing to OpenGL can do for a 2D game is better manage what goes into video memory vs. what stays in RAM, which matters a lot when blitting sprites to the right spot on the screen.

Comment: I'll look into Cocos2d-iPhone
Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

Several things :

- Don't use a timer. Use CADisplayLink. It's just like a timer, except it fires right on vsync. Look at Apple's doc.
- Yes, you definitely want to go the OpenGL|ES way. Here, the issue is that you push 40+ textures from the CPU to the GPU on each frame redraw. In OpenGL|ES you would be able to push all your texture once, and then just tell the GPU to "move" them around. This would be a lot more efficient. (i.e. solid 60fps, and very low CPU usage).